# git-friendly image format?

Tags: git, image-formats

For [repositories](https://jalsti.github.io/cov19de/pages/Deutschland.html) with daily updated data plots (including slightly changing background color gradients), I asked myself if there is some preferred format (or compression algorithm) to use, so that git can store them more efficiently, instead of having to re-write about 90% of them, all the time.

Is there any kind of image format which is more 'git-friendly' then others?

Comment: As long as it's a binary format - no. It might work better with SVG files - depending on how they are created

Comment: @fredrik It doesn't really matter since git will store the SVG files as different blobs anyway.

Comment: As far as I understand how git works, it may save your local repository space when packing the repo internals (it seems to use the deflate algorithm where possible and even use delta compression where possible (again, if I'm getting it correct) -- https://git-scm.com/docs/pack-format ). So, if the pack files do what I guess they really do, then you most likely don't need to migrate to other file formats.

Comment: @fluffy I'm pretty sure delta compression will only work with text files. If the SVG files are fully text, then the storage requirements will be noticeably smaller both on the server and the local sandbox, once that compression has been triggered. That's get significantly greater compression than the best Git can do compressing binary image files.

Comment: @fluffy I take it back. I read the documentation and ran a test, delta compression finds arbitrary common bytes sequences, it's not a text-diff algorithm. I just successfully compressed a repo using gc that had two big binary files sharing most of their contents, and `git gc` gave me significant savings indicating one was delta compressed from the other.

Comment: So he might consider going uncompressed image types like PNG so git can optimise the delta over time, since two relatively close pictures in this format will have a close binary representation, which is not necessarily the same for compressed format (e.g. JPEG ) (depends of his pictures and their variabilities each day)

Answer (score 3):

##### The theory

Formats that are "Git friendly" will be formats that share long identical byte sequences, whether they are binary or text.

Now, a lossy binary format will probably change most bytes when you change even just the background colour gradients, whereas a more descriptive text-based format might not.

##### Testing things with your own files

I recommend this test to calculate the compressed size of different file formats in your actual use case.

0. Before you start, take a sandbox or a clone, and aggressively compress it so we know further compression in later steps is not due to the images being added: run `git gc --aggressive` a few times, until `du .git` yields the same answer twice.

Now, for each file format you want to test, copy that sandbox into a new directory and do the following steps:

1. Add one set of images and aggressively compress the repo again by running `git gc --aggressive` a few times, until `du .git` yields the same answer twice.
2. Write down what `du .git` tells you: that's your baseline size.
3. Add and commit a new set of files, slightly changed in the way you describe in your question.
4. Now `du .git` tells you the size of just adding those files into the repo. On commit, Git does not (normally) try to apply delta compression or packing, it just add a new blob for each file being committed, unless an identical blob already existed.
5. Again, run `git gc --aggressive` until the size is stable.
6. Now `du .git` tells you how much Git was able to compress those files, by whatever means it found, possibly delta compression. The size here minus the size at step 2 is your space cost for adding one new set of files.

By running the above procedure for different file formats for your images, you'll get an answer specific to your use case.

##### Git LFS is probably your friend

PS: All that being said, I stand by @Nicolas Voron's answer: unless the size cost above is actually small for the file format you end up choosing, use Git LFS to avoid creating problems in the future when your repo gets too large to clone.

Answer (score 2):

Since git is not designed for (depsite the fact that it can) deal with binary files, I recommand you the excellent [git-lfs extension](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (originally suported by github):

Because with git, the problem is not what you are versionning, but how you do it.
Daily updated dataplots will generate a **huge** amount of data over time, which will be a problem in several years for cloning & fetching.

**How to use it :**

> Download and install the Git command line extension. Once downloaded
> and installed, set up Git LFS for your user account by running:
>
> `git lfs install` You only need to run this once per user account.
>
> In each Git repository where you want to use Git LFS, select the file
> types you'd like Git LFS to manage (or directly edit your
> .gitattributes). You can configure additional file extensions at
> anytime.
>
> `git lfs track` "*.psd" Now make sure .gitattributes is tracked:
>
> `git add .gitattributes` Note that defining the file types Git LFS
> should track will not, by itself, convert any pre-existing files to
> Git LFS, such as files on other branches or in your prior commit
> history. To do that, use the git lfs migrate[1](https://git-lfs.github.com/) command, which has a
> range of options designed to suit various potential use cases.
>
> There is no step three. Just commit and push to GitHub as you normally
> would; for instance, if your current branch is named main:
>
> `git add file.psd git`
>
> `commit -m "Add design file"`
>
> `git push origin main`

**What it does :**

> Git LFS stores a pointer file in the git repo in lieu of the real
> large file. The pointer is swapped out for the real file at checkout
> (using smudge and clean). The smudge and clean filters are part of
> core Git and are designed to allow changing a file on checkout
> (smudge) and on commit (clean). Git LFS uses these techniques to
> replace the pointer files with the actual large files that are in use.

**EDIT**

As i commented under your question, you might consider going uncompressed image types like PNG so git can optimise the delta over time, since two relatively close pictures in this format will have a close binary representation, which is not necessarily the same for compressed format (e.g. JPEG ) (it depends of your pictures and their variabilities each day, but since this is a plot, png should definitively do the trick).

Another recommendation is to handle pictures inside a submodule (unless it's a dedicated image-only repo), so the overweight of versionned images will not impact the whole repo for cloning & fetching.

Comment: This would basically mean moving the files out of git. Where I understand the process, I would really be interested in which file format would probably be the best for files inside git.

Comment: @Jaleks I edited my answer

Comment: Yes, maybe uncompressed PNG would be an option. Also maybe PNG-Filter type "Sub" may be promising, because it should yield similar rows of data at least for similar background gradients? Still uncompressed PNG would be worse for showing them on web, what the mentioned repo does.

Comment: To be honest, storing plot images makes no sense to me (especially if the software is web-based). Store datas and generate the graph front side is the best option imho (chart.js, plotly, etc...).

Comment: NO. All that JS stuff is no option. This is no playground. It should work everywhere. Pages should be fixed here, and the whole state of the site should be stored at once, in this approach. Also generating for example 50 plots, which each have 4 graphs + background gradient + expectation value, with daily data points from at least 2 years takes ages. And they shall be on one page. Already loading all that data to show them in tables takes ages. AND that JS generated data would not even get cached in the browser properly. Pre-generating/storing makes very much sense, JS not, like in most cases.

Comment: PNG is a compressed format.